# How to get several buttons' text at once in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, servlets

I have the following code, it's part of a Java servlet, html, javascript/jQuery web app.

```
  <Table border=1>
    <Tr>
      <Td><button id=Current_1 type=button></button></Td>
      <Td><button id=Current_2 type=button></button></Td>
      <Td><button id=Current_3 type=button></button></Td>
      <Td><button id=Current_4 type=button></button></Td>
      <Td><button id=Current_5 type=button></button></Td>
      <Td><button id=Current_6 type=button></button></Td>
    </Tr>
  </Table>
```

What can I do on the Java servlet side to get all the text in each of the buttons, I'm thinking about having another submit button when it's clicked, some jQuery gets all those buttons and loop through them to get each button's text.

The text in those buttons originally have nothing, but during the app user can click and change values, so at the end I need to give user a way to save the content on those buttons and pass them to the servlet, what's the best way to achieve that, any sample code ? But what I need help the most is how to get hold of the buttons and loop through them to get their text ?

Edit : Maybe I didn't express it very clearly.

```
If Button_1 has text "B1"
   Button_2 has text "B2"
   ...
   Button_6 has text "B6"
```

The result I expect after user click another submit button is : B1B2B3B4B5B6

Comment: Wouldn't the jquery selector $('button') return an array of all your buttons? So you then just do .html for all of your buttons and send that data to the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fairly simple to make array of objects using jQuery

```
var buttonData = $('button[id^="Current"]').map(function(){
   return {id: this.id, text: $(this).text()};
}).get();
```

Produces:

```
[
    {id:"Current_1", text: "Button #1 Text"}, 
    {id:"Current_2", text: "Button #2 Text"},
    ....
    {id:"Current_6", text: "Button #6 Text"}
]
```

A class selector would probably be cleaner or target them from selector on row

EDIT: If all you want is combined text with no delimiters you can actually get the whole collection of text without even looping the elements.

```
$('button[id^="Current"]').text();
```

for most value getters in jQuery this approach will only return the vlue of first element but with `text()` it returns all

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, simple and to the point, magical, thanks ^_^ !

Comment: to me it has always seemed like a bug because the behavior is so different than all the other getter methods...but here's a case where it helps

Comment: Yes, it's strange, never seen something like this before, but I tested it on Firefox,IE and Chrome, the behavior is consistent, and to my liking, very concise, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you can use another button to get the text of each of the button. Just use a common class and loop through them

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#Current_7").click(function(){
      $(".myButton").each(function(){
      console.log($(this).text())
      })   
   })
})
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/86n619f3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('button[id^="Current"]').each(function(){
        console.info($(this).attr('id') + '----' + $(this).text())        
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <Table border=1>
    <Tr>
      <Td><button id=Current_1 type=button>button_1</button></Td>
      <Td><button id=Current_2 type=button>button_2</button></Td>
      <Td><button id=Current_3 type=button>button_3</button></Td>
      <Td><button id=Current_4 type=button>button_4</button></Td>
      <Td><button id=Current_5 type=button>button_5</button></Td>
      <Td><button id=Current_6 type=button>button_6</button></Td>
    </Tr>                                
  </Table>
</body>
</html>
```